# IPA Keyboard for Linguistics.SE

Tags: script, editing

This script adds an IPA keyboard button to the editing toolbar

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/Extensions/IPAKeyboard/IPAKeyboard.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey). See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble or want to install it in another browser.
- If you use Noscript, [this bookmarklet](https://raw.github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/master/StackExchange/Extensions/IPAKeyboard/NoscriptBookmarklet.txt) is the way to go.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/Extensions/IPAKeyboard/IPAKeyboard.user.js)

### Usage

If you click the little schwa button on the editor, a keyboard will pop up. You can use it like any normal on-screen keyboard, just click on the symbols.

The blue circled letters are so that one can easily find a symbol<sup>1</sup> (they look similar to the symbols in their group). They also double up as keyboard shortcut indicators. For example, if you press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, hit <kbd>A</kbd> twice, and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you get the second symbol in the "A" group, that is, the a-e ligature. This lets you cycle between symbols rapidly, without even having to look at the keyboard. For example, a typical procedure would be to identify which letter the symbol looks like (pretty easy), hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, keep pressing that letter until the symbol shows up, then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>. If you can't find it, they keyboard is right there.

[image]

<sup>1. Idea taken from http://ipa.typeit.org/full/</sup>

Comment: Great! It works perfectly (except not with Noscript, see my comment on the Linguistics Meta.)

Comment: I have tested this script again, and it's great when it works. And it does work, but on some pages the right half gets cut off for me. On [this page](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124410/what-is-the-correct-use-of-present-participle-and-by-in-a-sequence-of-actions), for example, the right half gets cut off. I'm on the latest Firefox with Noscript and a bunch of other things. On the page you're reading now, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Cerberus Ah, that used to give me problems too. No guarantee about fixing it with NoScript, however I've noticed that the layout is very sensitive to site style. I'll try to rectify that (when I get time).

Comment: No worries, I realise that there is an infinite number of browser configurations! Can't help them all.

Comment: Installed on Chrome and I see "IPA Keyboard 1.0" enabled in the list of extensions.  But I refreshed this page and don't see that little "schwa" button...

Comment: @YanKingYin Are there any errors in the error console (Ctrl-Shift-J)?

Comment: Yes there seems to be an error -- debugger paused in jquery.min.js.

Comment: The error is from ajax.googleapis.com, maybe unrelated?  And I don't see IPA keyboard loaded as a content script in the "sources" tab.

Comment: @YanKingYin Unrelated then. Maybe Chrome isn't running it on the site? Which site are you running it on?

Comment: @YanKingYin hahaha, if you want I can set it up for all SE sites, but you probably don't want that :P

Comment: I actually want it to be used on unrelated websites... all input boxes... is it possible?  Can you point me some direction to do that? :)

Comment: @YanKingYin Copy the source from [here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/Extensions/IPAKeyboard/IPAKeyboard.user.js), save it as IPA.user.js, edit the line with "linguistics" on it to say `http://*.stackexchange.com`, and drag-drop this new file to the extensions directory. This won't work on Stack Overflow and sites that are not of the form `*.stackexchange.com`, so if you want it for them as well, I can provide you with a separate script.

Comment: Oh, wait, _all_ input boxes. Hmm. That's a bit tough, but you'd have to basically make changes starting from [this line](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/Extensions/IPAKeyboard/IPAKeyboard.js#L1063), and run it as a bookmarklet. I might make these changes later, but I'm busy for the next two weeks.